# access a class type variable from another class in swift

Tags: ios, swift, oop

I am trying to learn swift and i am reading this article https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html . In `VideoMode` class an object like `resolution` of type `Resolution` is created as a property of `VideoMode` class's .  After that an object `let someVideoMode = VideoMode()` of `VideoMode` class's is created and access `width` property of `Resolution` struct by `someVideoMode.resolution.width` . This concept is clear to me. But i am facing problem when i am reading this article https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH21-ID245

In this article `Person` class just create a property`var residence: Residence?` of `Residence` class's. Not create an object. After that, create a object `john` of `Person` class's and accessing  property of `Residence` class's. What is happening here? Please tell me, how  `Person` class access property of `Residence` class ?

Comment: Go back to ["The Basics"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309) and read about Optional values.

Comment: Not clear that you said. Would you please explain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In second case we have `optional` property and by default it initialize to `nil`.
If we look at what the optional type is, we will see that this is enum like:

```
enum Optional<T> {
    case Some(T)
    case None
}
```

And it can be `Some` Type like `Int` for example or `Residence` or `None` and in this case it's have nil value. And by default in your example it's `None` and in this code from documentation:

> ```
> if let roomCount = john.residence?.numberOfRooms {
>     print("John's residence has \(roomCount) room(s).")
> } else {
>     print("Unable to retrieve the number of rooms.")
> }
> ```

it will print

> "Unable to retrieve the number of rooms."

But if you init `residence` like this:

```
let john = Person()

// Init residence
john.residence = Residence()

if let roomCount = john.residence?.numberOfRooms {
    print("John's residence has \(roomCount) room(s).")
} else {
    print("Unable to retrieve the number of rooms.")
}
```

it will print:

> "John's residence has 1 room(s)."

because the optional type `enum` will return `Some(Residence)` and you will have access to it value

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer. But my question is not `optional ` related. I just want to know, how second article access class property without declaring object?

Comment: This is not the class property, it create object with default value of nil because it optional property